# Pandas doesnt recognize categorical -- access original codes when convert_categorical=True

Tags: python, pandas

I have a stata `.dta` file. If I open it in stata, I can see several columns with value labels. I can go into browse, click on one of them, and see the original code behind the label.

If I read this `.dta` file into `python` via `pd.read_stata(..., convert_categoricals=True)`, I can get the data types via `df.dtypes`.

For some of the columns, categories have been created. However, for one column of interest, instead a series with dtype `Object` has been created, which contains the labels as string.

1. How exactly does the process of category creation in pd.read_stata work?
2. How can I access the original data codes behind the labels when reading in with `convert_categorical=True`
3. What do I do in the case where columns are converted into dtype `Object` -- do I have to read in the data frame a second time with `convert_categoricals=False` and merge? That really sounds non-pythonic.