# How to access categorical data which is saved as object in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `.dta` data which I load with `df = pd.read_stata('mydata.dta', convert_categoricals=True)`. When I convert the categories from Stata I can more easily "see" what my categories are about. But I cannot find an option to handle data in this format. It's actually converted to strings/object.

I found a similar problem without any answers on SA: [Pandas doesnt recognize categorical — access original codes when convert_categorical=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468487/pandas-doesnt-recognize-categorical-access-original-codes-when-convert-catego)

My workaround is to not convert the cats from dta. `df = pd.read_stata('mydata.dta', convert_categoricals=False)` Then calculation etc. is possible, but I have to look up all the categories by hand. That is not very pythonic.

It's really difficult to MWE the situation. It's somehow like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['1988', '1988', '1988', '1988', '1989', '1989', '1989', '1989'],
                  'money': ['5', '7', '8', '8', '3', '3', '7', '8']}).astype(int)

health = ['2 [good]', '-2 [not applicable]', '3 [ok]', '1 [excellent]', '3 [ok]', '5 [bad]', '2 [good]', '1 [excellent]']
df['health'] = health
df.info() # health is an object

# df.loc[(df.health >= 2) & (df.year=1988), 'money'] # not working
```

Within my analysis I would like to check the money for people in good health in a given year. But categories are strings. I have a lot of variables and categories.

How to tell the dataframe use "the number in front of brackets"?

What is the correct way to handle "values" and "labels" of categories in dataframe? What is the correct data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is necessary use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get values to new columns from `health` values:

```
df[['a','b']] = df['health'].str.extract('([-]?\d+)\s+\[(.+)\]')
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(int)
print (df)
   year  money               health  a               b
0  1988      5             2 [good]  2            good
1  1988      7  -2 [not applicable] -2  not applicable
2  1988      8               3 [ok]  3              ok
3  1988      8        1 [excellent]  1       excellent
4  1989      3               3 [ok]  3              ok
5  1989      3              5 [bad]  5             bad
6  1989      7             2 [good]  2            good
7  1989      8        1 [excellent]  1       excellent
```

Comment: So I always have to extract the numerical value from the string? And the only way to keep track of the "meaning/label" is to save it to another column? I mean, I have like 10 such variables, it should still be possible. But it doesn't look very elegant to me. Is there no way to store value and label in one cell of the df? best regards

Comment: @MarcoDoe - It depends what you need. The best pandas working if scalars in columns - so numeric columns separately and strings columns separately.